# Display selected text in a jsp page

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp, web

Hi I am a newbie in JSP and was trying to show the selected value in a header as a dynamic text. But every time I select it shows the option value not the text. below is what I have tried.

Html drop down

```
<select id="country" name="country_code">
       <option value="1">Puerto Rico</option>
       <option value="63">Philippines</option>
       <option value="others">Others</option>
</select>
```

JSP tag

```
    <%
        String countrycd = request.getParameter("country_code");
        String countryTxt = request.getParameter("country_code");
    %>
```

This is my script

```
    <script>
        document.getElementById("country").value = '<% out.print(countrycd); %>';
        var e= document.getElementById("country");
        var str = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
        alert(str);
    </script>
```

This is my html code where I need to show the selected text instead of value for example if user selects Philippines it should show as Philippines not the code 63

```
<h2>By Country: <% out.print(countrycd);</h2>
```

Any help would be really appriciated!

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

Current Output

> From drop down philipines is selected in header it shows: By Country:
>   63

Expected output:

> From drop down if philipines is selected it should show
>
> By Country: Philipines not 63.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're showing the value in the header. You could accomplish it by doing:

```
<h2>By Country: <span id="countryName"> </span> </h2>
```

And then your `script` should be:

```
<script>
  window.onload = function(){        
    document.getElementById("country").value = '<% out.print(countrycd); %>';
    var e= document.getElementById("country");
    var str = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;

    document.getElementById("countryName").innerHTML = str;  //This line changed
  };
</script>
```

Instead of getting the country name with JSP, we do it with javascript (writing it inside the `countryName` span)

Cheers, from La Paz, Bolivia

Comment: Thank you Edgar, I did the same but it doesn't show any values when I select values from the drop down and click the submit button? Do I have to include anything else to show the selected value?? or save it using JSP parameter??

Comment: Welcome. When you select a country, and then submit the form, does the alert show the new selected country code?

Comment: Yes, I have added the alert to see if it pop up the value, and when I select it does alert the text but doesn't show any thing after-> 'BY Country: '

Comment: earlier when I added this <h2> By Country <% out.print(countrycd); %></h2> it use to show just the id not the value. Do you think there has to be something like that to get the text instead?

Comment: Hmm.. I see. Is your `<script>` tag before the `<h2>` tag?

Comment: Yes, the script is before my h2 tag

Comment: That's the problem :). Put it after your `<h2>` tag (preferably just before closing the body), and let me know

Comment: Amazing! it worked :) Thank you so much does the ordering matters? I did not knew let me study more on that. Thank you so much :)

Comment: Welcome :). The problem is that when you called the script, the `countryName` span didn't exist in the html yet. Just in case I'm editing the answer (adding `window.onload`)so order doesn't matter and you can put your script anywhere.

Comment: Great! it does make sense now, Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

The behavior of the select component in HTML is to send the value of the selected option when the form is posted rather than the display text. You can achieve your objective in one of 2 ways:

Change the select like this:

```
   <select id="country" name="country_code">
       <option value="Puerto Rico">Puerto Rico</option>
       <option value="Philippines">Philippines</option>
       <option value="Others">Others</option>
   </select>
```

Or if the value represents an id of the country in a database you can look it up when the form is posted and get the name of the country that way.

Comment: Thank you Vincent for your reply. Yes thats right, I basically need the value which is id of each country to look it up in database and retrieve the records. But in the JSP page I need to show the name of the country instead of the id. Please suggest.